# Why does hackerrank provide constraints and then ignore them?

Tags: python

There are others but this example will get the point across
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/collections-counter/problem

The constraints say: `20 < price < 100` and `2 < shoe_size < 20` which means price does not include 20 or 100 and shoe_size does not include 2 or 20 ... so why in their testing data do they require that you include this invalid data for you to get the "correct" answer?

Note: The data which includes this is in a data_set, answer pair I bought to try and figure out why I was not passing all of the tests.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Hackerrank's implementation is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please ask this question on **hackerrank** forum, or on their [#irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=hackerrank) channel

Comment: IMO if hackerrank is off topic for stack overflow there shouldn't be a hackerrank tag ... just saying

Comment: @bhansa Thanks, I am attempting to get an answer in their IRC, I already posted on their forum but haven't received a reply, hence my attempt here.  I figured it could be helpful to others as it is a general question about a widely used programming site. ... received a response ... some dude in the IRC says report it as an issue, and given that I see this frequently I should report it frequently ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided via IRC at bhansa's suggestion.  The guy/gal that answered wasn't associated with hackerrank but (s)he suggested to report it as an issue and this was not supposed to be a normal behavior regardless of how frequently I have seen it pop up.